# SQL: Select only users who are new in 2021

Tags: sql

If we have a table as follows:

| User_ID | Order_date | Order_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-02-02 | 23 |
| 2 | 2021-03-03 | 45 |
| 1 | 2021-02-02 | 13 |
| 3 | 2019-05-23 | 34 |
| 3 | 2021-01-31 | 56 |

How to select only the user whose first order is in the year 2021 (in this case, only User 2)?

Comment: What have *you* tried? Why didn't it work? I am more than certain there are examples of how to achieve this already on  [so]; when you looked at those solutions what about them didn't you understand? What RDBMS you are *really* using? SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having min(order_date) >= '2021-01-01';
```

This checks that the earliest order date is after the first of the year.